# Why inline javascript doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

This piece of code doesn't work on my firefox 12 browser.

```
javascript:alert("hi");
```

But it works on IE8.

What's the problem?

Comment: see http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/876916#answer-248299

Comment: @Esailija That is the answer, you should post it below.

Comment: you need to post more code, where is this being used on the page?

Comment: ok.but why -2 ??! so funny...

Comment: Hi Milad, to answer your question, the downvotes are likely because users believe you didn't do any research before posting here. StackOverflow is designed to be a resource of knowledge, but when questions are asked that are already easily findable on the Internet or that don't show research effort, those questions that *do* show effort, research, and involve a real problem end up getting pushed down the page by clutter, and Esailija pretty much found that Mozilla link within minutes of you posting this question. Before posting new questions, consider doing a search first. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

see http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/876916#answer-248299

> You can no longer run JavaScript code via the location bar in Firefox
>   6 and later. You can see an error message in the Tools > Error
>   Console. That code now gets a null principal for security reasons and
>   doesn't have any effect (Bug 656433). You need to create a (keyword)
>   bookmarklet and run the code by invoking that bookmark.
>
> NoScript can allow you to run such code via the location bar, see:
>
> ```
> http://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=6488&p=27991
> ```

Google chrome has a different approach, if you copypaste `javascript:` to your location bar, it will be silently swallowed. You can only run it if you directly write it out in the location bar.

Both browsers come with a built-in console that can be used to run code that affects the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Install firebug and you can run it on the console (by typing F12) and:

```
 alert("hi");
```

[Firebug Addon Download Page](https://addons.mozilla.org/ca/firefox/addon/firebug/)